# Reference request: Where is this functional equation found?

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations

$$
g\left(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right) = g(x)g(y).
$$
One solution is
$$
g(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}.
$$
Another is
$$
g(x) = \sqrt\frac{1+x}{1-x}.
$$
Any other power of the first solution is also a solution, but for the moment I suspect the second one may be in some reasonable sense the natural one.

**Is there a standard name of this functional equation?**

**Is there an extensive literature?**

**Does it occur naturally in some particular field?**

**Are there interesting results?  What are they?**

Comment: A comment: use the change of variables $x=\tanh z$ to reduce to a more tractable functional equation.

Comment: The [Relativistic Doppler shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) when the source is moving towards/away the direction of the observer.

Comment: This didn't seem to have much of a "tractability" problem, since I quickly solved the equation immediately after I wrote it down.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\gg}{{\rm g}}$
$\ds{\gg\pars{x + y \over 1 + xy} = \gg\pars{x}\gg\pars{y}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \gg'\pars{x + y \over 1 + xy}\,{1 - y^{2} \over \pars{1 + xy}^{2}} &= \gg'\pars{x}\gg\pars{y}
> \\[3mm]
> \gg'\pars{x + y \over 1 + xy}\,{1 - x^{2} \over \pars{1 + xy}^{2}} &= \gg\pars{x}\gg'\pars{y}
> \end{align}
> which leads to
> $\ds{{1 - y^{2} \over 1 - x^{2}} = {\gg'\pars{x}\gg\pars{y} \over \gg\pars{x}\gg'\pars{y}}\quad\imp\quad
> \pars{1 - x^{2}}\,{\gg'\pars{x} \over \gg\pars{x}}
> =
> \pars{1 - y^{2}}\,{\gg'\pars{y} \over \gg\pars{y}} = C}$. $C$ is a constant. Then,
> \begin{align}
> &\ln\pars{\verts{g}}
> =\int{\dd\gg \over g}
> = \half\,C\int{\dd x \over 1 - x^{2}} + \overbrace{D}^{\ds{\mbox{constant}}}
> =
> \half\,C\int\pars{{1 \over x - 1} - {1 \over 1 + x}}\,\dd x + D
> \\[3mm]&=
> \half\,C\ln\pars{\verts{x - 1 \over x + 1}} + D
> \end{align}

$$
\ln\pars{\verts{\gg\pars{x}}} = \half\,C\ln\pars{\verts{x - 1 \over x + 1}} + D\,,
\qquad C, D: \mbox{constants}
$$
$$
\verts{\gg\pars{x}} = A\verts{x - 1 \over x + 1}^{C/2}\,,\qquad A:\mbox{constant}
$$

1. $\gg\pars{0} = 0$ leads to the trivial solution
       $\gg\pars{x} = 0\,,\ \forall\ x$.
2. $\gg\pars{0} = 1$ yields
       $\ds{\verts{\gg\pars{x}} = \verts{x - 1 \over x + 1}^{C/2}}$.
3. What else ?.

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't actually answer any of the questions.